# Вопрос по туле Jmeter №2, прошу оказать помощь по возможности

Tags: jmeter, qaction, qapplication

[image: Скрин]

Правильно ли я понимаю:

1. Неограниченное количество итераций на одного пользователя?
2. Вот это вообще не понял: " to determine the "protocol" and "server name" parameters."
3. По этому пункту прошу знатоков тоже оказать помощь по возможности
4. Правильно ли я понимаю, что тут подразумевается "Ramp-up period"?
5. Это понятно, View Result Tree создан

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Да, судя по всему 1 виртуальный пользователь и неограниченное количество итераций
2. Если вы укажете протокол и IP адрес или DNS Hostname в [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) - эти поля можно оставить пустыми в [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) сэмплерах, если они будут в [области видимости](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) HTTP Request Defaults - значения будут взяты оттуда
3. Речь идет о том чтобы создать CSV файл с параметрами для 20 запросов и настроить [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) для того чтобы читать этот файл, тогда каждый пользователь в каждой новой итерации будет брать следующую строчку из файла и каким-то образом использовать ее в запросе в виде [переменной](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
4. Да и это можно игнорировать потому что пользователь у вас всего один
5. Вообще-то [не рекомендуется использовать этот элемент](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) ни для чего кроме как создания/отладки теста